# RegEx for Isracard (Israel Card)

Tags: javascript, c#, regex

I need a Regular expression for Isracard (Israel Credit Card).

Would be very grateful for help, or maybe for some info how to make it.

Format of Isracard 8-9 digits.

ex. Picture of card  - http://images.delcampe.com/img_large/auction/000/157/341/572_001.jpg

Comment: What is the format of Isracard. please add some details

Answer (score 6):

I found a validation for IsraCard:

```
<script>
    var cardValid=function(cardNo){    
    var sum = 0, iNum;
    for( var i in cardNo+='' ){
        iNum = parseInt(cardNo[i]);
        sum += i%2?iNum:iNum>4?iNum*2%10+1:iNum*2;
    }
    return !(sum%10);
  };
</script>


Asp vb script IsraCard Credit Card number Validation (8 or 9 digits)

<%
Function IsraCardCheck(strNumber)
    comp1 = "987654321"
    comp2 = strNumber
    srez = 0
    if len(comp2) < 9 then comp2 = "0" & comp2
    for i = 1 to 9 
        a = mid(comp1, i, 1)
        b = mid(comp2, i, 1)
        c = a * b
        srez = srez + c
    next

    if srez mod 11 = 0 then
        IsraCheck = true
    else
        IsraCheck = false
    end if
End Function 
%>
```

I just copied the code from there and for more information and details you may want to check the link itself: [Anatomy of credit card number formats](http://www.wysiwyg.co.il/anatomy-of-creditcard-number-formats.asp)

Answer (score 5):

Based on what I see [here](http://www.stevemorse.org/ssn/List_of_Bank_Identification_Numbers.html) (and without any further guidelines from you on on what an Israel credit card number begins with), this should probably work

```
(3640|4580)-?([0-9]{4}-?){3}
```

Comment: Note, there is now more information present so my answer doesn't correlate with that the OP wanted :)

Answer (score 3):

A simple regex to check if it's a number with 8 or 9 digits:

```
^[0-9]{8,9}$
```

Or if a space or dash is allowed between the digits.

```
^[0-9](?:[ -]?[0-9]){7,8}$
```

To match for example :

```
1234-5678-9
1234 5678
1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9
1-2-3-4-5-6-7-8
12-34 56-78 9
```

But a pure regex can't do calculations, like f.e. a modulus check.
So extra code is needed to give a more accurate validation.

**Javascript example snippet:**

```js
function checkIsracard(creditcardNo){
    if(! /^[0-9](?:[ -]?[0-9]){7,8}$/.test(creditcardNo.toString())) return false;
    let total = 0;
    let cardDigits = creditcardNo.toString().match(/[0-9]/g);
    cardDigits.forEach(function(digit, indx){
        total += parseInt(digit,10)*(cardDigits.length - indx);
    });
    return (total%11 === 0);
}

console.log('1234-5678-9:\t'+checkIsracard('1234-5678-9'));
console.log('1234 5679:\t'+checkIsracard('1234 5679'));
console.log('123456789:\t'+checkIsracard(123456789));
console.log('12345679:\t'+checkIsracard(12345679));
console.log('123456781:\t'+checkIsracard('123456781'));   // modulus check fail
console.log('12345671:\t'+checkIsracard('12345671'));     // modulus check fail
console.log('1234567:\t'+checkIsracard('1234567'));       // not enough digits
console.log('1234567890:\t'+checkIsracard('1234567890')); // too many digits
```

But if the question would be about the [16 digit visa credit card numbers](https://www.creditcardvalidator.org/visa/israel-credit-cards/458028)?
For those, the more widely used [luhn-algorithm](https://www.creditcardvalidator.org/articles/luhn-algorithm) is used.
So that algorithm  would be a bit more complicated.

Answer (score 1):

Algorithm explanation: https://web.archive.org/web/20140227235803/http://povolotski.me/2013/09/24/isracard-credit-card-number-validation-2/

```
function isracardCheck(num) {
    if(typeof num !== 'number') num=''+num;
    if(num.length < 8 || num.length > 9) return false;
    var sum=0;
    num.split('').forEach(function(val,key){
        sum+=parseInt(val,10)*(num.length-key);
        })
    return sum % 11 == 0;
    }
```

License: MIT, https://gist.github.com/avimar/e7421f96357bf06acc31d952c7baf84e